# How to get new generated url after using clickElement function from RSelenium package

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I would like to know how to get a `url` after using the `clickElement` function from R's `RSelenium` package.
Here's an example:

```r
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"), 
               chromever = "98.0.4758.102", 
               #extraCapabilities = list(chromeOptions = list(args = list("--headless"))),
               port = 4580L)

driver <- rD[["client"]]

urll <- "https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/venda/fazendas-sitios-chacaras/ms+campo-grande/?pagina=1"

driver$navigate(urll)
 
linkimovdescr <- driver$findElement(using = "xpath",
                                    "/html/body/main/section[1]/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/div[1]")
                 
linkimovdescr$clickElement()
```

Here's the question! How to get the address `"https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/imovel/venda-fazenda-sitio-chacara-parque-do-sol-campo-grande-ms-240m2-id-2531139106/"`

Note: The `linkimovdescr$getCurrentUrl()` or `driver$getCurrentUrl()` command does not answer my question, as it keeps pointing to the home page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As new tab opens when you click the item, thus we need to switch tabs in order to get url.

1.Clicking the item

```
linkimovdescr <- driver$findElement(using = "xpath",
                                    "/html/body/main/section[1]/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/div[1]")
                 
linkimovdescr$clickElement()
```

2.Now get the list of all the tabs by `getWindowHandles`

```
df =  driver$getWindowHandles()
```

3.Now switch to the second tab

```
driver$switchToWindow(df[[2]])
```

4.Get the url,

```
driver$getCurrentUrl() 
[[1]]
[1] "https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/imovel/venda-fazenda-sitio-chacara-zona-rural-campo-grande-ms-30000m2-id-2552129433/"
```

Comment: Hi Nad! Are you using another browser? Because it didn't work for me. Such commands still keep returning the first url. Thanks for the try.

Comment: I used `firefox`, but it shouldn't make difference

Comment: You are mistaken! I tested it in firefox and it worked. Thank you very much. Should I report what happened to the package maintainers?

Comment: Sure, you can bring it to their attention.